# XPath 2.0 feature in JDOM 2.0

Tags: java, xpath-2.0, jdom-2

How can I use XPath 2.0 feature like "schema-element" in JDOM 2.0?

Is this even possible? If so, how?

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no XPath 2.0 engine linked in to JDOM. As far as I know there is no XPath 2.0 support linked in to any non-XSLT-based XML processing library (JDOM/XOM/DOM/etc.). I have worked with Saxon to integrate XPath 2.0 and it is likely that the upcoming version 2.1 of JDOM will have XPath 2.0 support by leveraging the Saxon library.

Rolf